# Jquerymobile filter listview not working when fetching data dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Jquerymobile filter listview not working when fetching data dynamically

the code for displaying data using url getfilms.php

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "./getfilms.php";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        //var arr = obj.records;
        var i;
        var out = "";
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<li><a href ='" + arr[i].Path + "'>" + arr[i].Film + "</a></li>";
        }
        document.getElementById("searchfilmsbyname").innerHTML = out;
    }
```

The code for displaying the listview in html side using id="searchfilmsbyname"

```
<ul data-role="listview"  data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search films..." data-inset="true" id="searchfilmsbyname">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code  . use `$( ".selector" ).listview( "refresh" );` method when add dynamic data to listview . read more here about [refresh](https://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh)

```
 function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    //var arr = obj.records;
    var i;
    var out = "";
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<li><a href ='" + arr[i].Path + "'>" + arr[i].Film + "</a></li>";
     if((i+1) == arr.length){
         document.getElementById("searchfilmsbyname").innerHTML = out;
         //  $("#searchfilmsbyname").html( out );  you can use this jquery method to add html inside list view
         $("#searchfilmsbyname").listview('refresh');
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: i want to add dynamic link here like "<li><a href ='#filmdetails' onclick='fetchFilmDetails()' data-ajax='false'>" + arr[i].Film + "</a></li>" which will load on click to  filmdetails  id and fetch data from php such as filmdetails.php?filmId=3 and will display.

Comment: @RRPandey "filmdetails" is different page id ?

Comment: i am using jquerymobile so its id wich will fetch data from filmdetails.php?filmId=3 to this id. fetchFilmDetails does not work

Comment: yes but what i say in jquery mobile pages is load base on id right ? so what i am asking is `'#filmdetails'` is page id where you load data when page load or its element on current page need to load data in same page ?

Comment: page id is film and div id is #filmdetails

Comment: is it possible to create fiddle ? not able to understand why you pass `href ='#filmdetails' `  if you want to load data then it will work using ajax with jquery click event

Comment: i am creating mobile android app when i made the apk file nothing with working whether is ajax or json. need some other solution

Comment: why ajax will not work ? if you are using phongap they provide local database plugin . also all ajax request will work why not .. you are nota ble to run  php file in apk